# Need to concatenate multiple string variables in calculated fields using jasper server domain designer

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I need to concatenate three string variable as one field while creating the domain using *JasperReports Server* domain designer.

Example: s1=ram
         s2=jak
         s3=dak

here i need a calculated field as d=ram jak dak.

Answer (score 0):

You can use calculated fields with the .concat() function like this:

s1.concat( s2, " ", s3 )

Or you can create this with derived table.